# Debugger not working for C++ Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to debug my C++ code with gdb, but every time I set a breakpoint and press F5, it just doesn't do anything. I hover over the breakpoint and it says "Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained." even if I put a breakpoint right on main! Here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in addition, the little menu that pops up, the step over, step into, step out buttons are all greyed out. I can only pause, restart, or stop the debugging (that isn't happening).

I compile and run my program with this

```
g++ inputbuf.cc lexer.cc parser.cc -o a.out && a.out < tests/no_errors/test_01.txt > output.txt
```

Also, the double backslash for the gdb path "\\" vs "/" in launch.json doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try adding `-g` to the compiler flags.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. still doesn't work. i assume this is a problem with the input /output redirection. I've done 



```"args": ["<", "${workspaceFolder}/tests/no_errors/test_01.txt", " >", "output.txt"]``` 




in my launch.json but it still doesn't do anything, the toolbar is just greyed out